# Performance and memory of algorithmic implementations in Python

Tags: python, c++, performance, numpy, memory

Python has many libraries like numpy and pandas that are implemented in lower levels which as I understand makes the performance as good as using the same libraries in the lower level languages.

I am used to implementing algorithms that require high computations and high memory using C++
I can know exactly how much memory I am using and in terms of performance it is definitely faster than pure python.

But if an algorithm is implemented in python where all the computation is done using libraries like numpy and pandas, how does the performance compare to implementing the same algorithm in C++?

Comment: Only way to know is to benchmark it. There's no general answer to this since different functions have different complexity.

Comment: Short answer: numpy/pandas will probably be several times faster than anything you write in pure C++, since both leverage libraries like BLAS that do the heavy lifting in Fortran code that has been optimized for 30 years.

Comment: To that point Arne, let’s say I am implementing k-means clustering as a module and my goal is to be used in python. It would be better to implement it in python using numpy/pandas than C++ then wrap it to python?

Comment: While doing that c++ wrapping part, you are most probably trying to re-code something that's been thoroughly tested, and used by thousands. I strongly think it's better to go with numpy/pandas, unless something is not possible at all with them.

Comment: The rule of thumb: make it work first. Optimize later if necessary. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.